Why does the finite trace of density matrix imply a discrete Schmidt decomposition?
In the paper defining an average Schmidt number for a particular entangled system, Law and Eberly say:

Because density matrices always have finite trace, the Schmidt decomposition is always discrete, even when the original specification of the state is naturally continuous

They do not proceed to prove it or refer to any such proof. I am looking for a reason as to why a finite trace of the density matrix implies discrete Schmidt decomposition.
EDIT: Schmidt decomposition is the eigenvalue decomposition of the reduced density matrix.

Can you include some context? What exactly is "Schmidt-decomposed" here? Without this context, the question is ill-posed and cannot be answered.

I really don't understand the question/statement. You can introduce the Schmidt-decomposition without defining/knowing anything about density operators. The SD is always "discrete" in the sense that you can always find two orthonormal bases of the respective Hilbert spaces s.t. the well-known decomposition holds.

Regarding your edit: It is still not clear what you mean. See my second comment. I'd just ignore this sentence in the paper... But anyway, here is what I think they mean: Density operators are, by definition, trace-class and non-negative, and hence in particular compact and self-adjoint. This in turn implies that there exists an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors. Also, the spectrum consists of eigenvalues of finite multiplicity and possibly $0$ as an accumulation point (only $0$ can possibly be in the continuous spectrum).
